# How to change the color of some colored pixels on a texture?

Tags: java, colors, textures, lwjgl

I have a black and white texture(800*600 pixels) and I want to change the black pixels to black but quite transparent and change the white pixels to completely transparent.

I've tried using the obvious: take the FloatBuffer with texture data and running a for-loop. Like this for the black pixels:

```
FloatBuffer data; //The texture data (rgba)
float[] change = new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1}; //Current black color
float[] insert = new float[]{0, 0, 0, 0.5f}; //The new transparent black color

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4){
    if(data.get(i) == change[0] && data.get(i+1) == change[1] && data.get(i+2) == change[2] && data.get(i+3) == change[3]){
        data.put(i, insert[0]);
        data.put(i+1, insert[1]);
        data.put(i+2, insert[2]);
        data.put(i+3, insert[3]);
    }
}
```

This turned out to be very very slow, I looked around on the Internet and found this shaders thing. So my question is:

Should I use some sort of shaders code, are there some built in method in opengl/lwjgl or is this a thing I need to do on the cpu and in that case what is the best way?

Sorry for the horrible title and for some spelling problems, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can optimize your existing code to increase its speed:

You could greatly speed this up by not calling data.get() four times in your if statement but instead by getting all the pixel at once and checking that against your black color. This is the biggest bottle neck I see in your code.

Another way to speed it up would just be to ignore the Alpha color data if you can assume that all alpha data for the black pixels is set to 1 or something close to it.

A third way to optimize would be to check the RGB data as integers instead of floats.

Finally, I'm not sure how FloatBuffer and data.get()/put() works, but if you're opening and closing the file each time, that's going to be very slow. Read into memory once, make your changes, and then write the file out only once.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still running really slow. Only increased by about 8fps. Do you know any way of doing this on the gpu?

Comment: Are you trying to render the results of this in realtime?

Comment: Yes, it's like an overlay.

Comment: Some additional options: Do the pixel processing concurrently on a thread. Process the image buffer before rendering rather than after. To do it on the GPU directly you'd want to use a Pixel Shader: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_shader#Pixel_shaders -- Sorry, I would've suggested these much earlier but for some reason my default assumption was that you were just transforming a single image.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, do you know any simple way of doing this using shaders? I've got some problem understanding them.

Comment: Usually when people use shaders they do so by directly hitting OpenGL or DirectX API. Here's a simple example with OpenGL using Java: http://schabby.de/opengl-shader-example/